# How to install a .bar file hosted in a remote server to a BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha device

Tags: blackberry-10, remote-server

I have port an Android application to BlackBerry using ***Android Runtime***. I can install that application successfully using ***Eclipse***. Now I want to put those deploy files (MyApp.bar) in to a remote server and download the **.bar** file using a browser and install it to another **BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha device**. I was able to download but unable to install the .bar file. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for an app or tool that you can run from a BB10 device itself to install the .bar file, after you've already downloaded it.  There [used to be a tool](http://forums.crackberry.com/playbook-apps-games-f243/localbar-install-bar-files-directly-your-playbook-667235/#post6826960) like this for the Playbook, but it seems to be no longer maintained and Blackberry (RIM) have blocked the method this app used to perform the install in newer version of the Playbook OS (and presumably BB10 as well).

A solution which has been [reported to work](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Install-bar-over-a-BB-10-Dev-Alphe-device/td-p/1962869) by some in the Blackberry Developer forums is the [Playbook App Manager](http://gridbook.org/pb-app-mgr/) as a Firefox or [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/playbook-app-manager/kmbaalodpmjjhpobkgljnelbpblnikkp). You can use this plugin from the browser on your PC to push the .bar to your other Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha device over the network.

If that doesn't work, that leaves you only with external tools that you already know work like the Eclipse plugin, and you could also use the [command line tools](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/running_unsigned_applications_using_a_debug_token_1727941_11.html) like `blackberry-deploy` or `batchbar-deploy` installed with the SDK.

Finally, crackberry.com has a [tutorial on sideloading](http://crackberry.com/how-put-android-apps-your-blackberry-10-device) Android apps using the [DDPB](http://ddpb.dauden.vn/) third party app, which requires Java and .Net (so the browser plugin tool is really preferred).

Comment: The link you gave in the [BlackBerry Developer Forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Install-bar-over-a-BB-10-Dev-Alphe-device/td-p/1962869) is the method I was searching for. Thank you very much.